# Broadcast Receiver not restarting after reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get my Broadcast Receiver to run right after boot. From what I am aware the broadcast receiver will run regardless of rebooting and I just learnt that, but my problem is that I have set it up to run at midnight every night and I don't want to wait till midnight to run it once as that defeats the purpose. But I need it to run right after reboot once. But it is not running. Can someone see if I am doing something wrong? I am trying this on a Galaxy S4 and S6 and get not log message stating that it has rebooted.

This is my Manifest file, as you can see it is the necessary permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
<receiver
        android:name=".StartActivityAtBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And in my StartActivityAtBootReceiver I have the onReceive with the call to the main activity which will start the broadcast receiver.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("LOGS", "Start Activity after Rebooted ");
    Intent rebootIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    rebootIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(rebootIntent);
}
```

In my MainActivity I have the following which calls the broadcast receiver in another class that extends the Broadcast Receiver.

```
//run from boot or from button on screen
protected void runFromOutside() throws ParseException {
    checkIfStartingNow();
    startTheClock();
    finish(); //close the app/view
}

//check if starting now pops up message to state that it is staring now
protected void checkIfStartingNow() throws ParseException {
//does some checks and displays a message popup
}

  protected void startTheClock() {

    // Set the alarm to run at midnight every night
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
    //calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 01);
    // Get the AlarmManager Service
    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    // Create an Intent to broadcast to the Shhh
    mNotificationReceiverIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Shhh.class);

    // Create an PendingIntent that holds the NotificationReceiverIntent
  //  mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, mNotificationReceiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, mNotificationReceiverIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Set repeating alarm that checks every minute.
    mAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, mNotificationReceiverPendingIntent);

    // set true for alarm
    settings.edit().putBoolean(NotificationOn, true).apply();
    Log.e("LOGS", "Entered Start the midnight alarm");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK So I figured it out, the reason it was not working was because the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` was not in the correct place in the Android Manifest file, so in the end I had to move it outside of the `application` tag (the correct place to put it), then the reboot worked. So make sure that you have the correct XML layout in your Android Manifest file as I learnt the hard way as it can cause havoc in your app.

The `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` was inside the `application` tag so it never worked. VERY IMPORTANT. Hope this helps someone else in the future. So make sure your XML tags are in the right place.